# Pass current sku number to the custom phtml form before submission ( data-bind, placeholder)

Tags: magento2, forms, phtml, contact-form

i'm trying to past the value of $current_sku to the end the $title text field input on the form. How can I achieve it? Correctly, it's showing in the text input hints..

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
?>

<!--get product sku-->      <?php $current_sku = $product->getSku(); ?>             
<div class="field required">
                    <label class="label" for="amfaq-title">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your question:')); ?>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea name="title"
                                  id="amfaq-title"
                                  title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Question')); ?>"
                                  class="required-entry input-text"
                                  cols="5"
                                  rows="3"
                                  data-bind="value: title"
                                  placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Type your question here ...')) .'('. $current_sku .')' ;?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually, i create an onclick event for the submit button used JavaScript to add the text when the submit button is clicked

> getting sku number through object manager

```
    <?php 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $current_sku = $product->getSku(); ?>  // get sku number

                <fieldset class="fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?= __('* Required Fields'); ?>">
                    <div class="field required">
                        <label class="label" for="amfaq-title">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your question:')); ?>
                        </label>
                        <div class="control">               
                            <textarea name="title"
                                      id="amfaq-title"
                                      title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Question')); ?>"
                                      class="required-entry input-text"
                                      cols="5"
                                      rows="3"
                                      data-bind="value: title"
                                      placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Type your question here ...'));?>" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

> submit button with onclick event

```
        <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" onclick="addText(event)">  <!--add onclick event here -->
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Send the Question')); ?>
        </button>
```

> script to add sku when submit is clicked

```
<script>
function addText(event) {
    var pn = "<?php echo ' (' . $current_sku . ')'?>";
    document.getElementById("amfaq-title").value += pn;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Value Property in yout Textarea :-**

```
    <div class="control">
           <textarea name="title"
                id="amfaq-title"
                value = "<?php echo $current_sku ?>"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Question')); ?>"
                class="required-entry input-text"
                cols="5"
                rows="3"
                data-bind="value: title"
                placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Type your question here ...')) .'('. $current_sku .')' ;?>"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: adding value property didn't seems to sohw in this case. is there another way around? or possible add to the end of user's  textarea input before form submission? thanks.